# Spinner Selection Crash

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-spinner

On 1st time selection the audio plays for every one of them as it should but Whenever I try to reselect a name from the spinner that has already been played or selected, the app crashes.

At first I thought it was the links but then I checked the links and they were fine. The array's are also in order.

```
    private val links = mapOf(
    
            **"Billy" to "https://Billy_voice.mp3"** 
            **"Sam" to "https://Sam_voice.mp3"**
    )
    private fun getCharacterInfo(selectedCharacter: String): String {
        return when (selectedCharacter) {
            **"Billy"-> """InfoInfoInfoInfoInfoInfoInfo"""**.trimMargin()
            **"Sam"-> """InfoInfoInfoInfoInfoInfoInfo"""**.trimMargin()
            else -> "No info available for this character."
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.charecter_selection)
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.characters)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.characterSelection)
        characterInfoTV = findViewById(R.id.characterInfoTV)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Character_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            var previousPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                textView.text = selectedItem
                characterInfoTV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                characterInfoTV.text = getCharacterInfo(selectedItem)
                spinner.prompt = "Select Your Character"
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Selected: $selectedItem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                previousPlayer?.let {
                    if (it.isPlaying) {
                        it.stop()
                    }
                    it.release()
                }
                val selectedLink = links[selectedItem]
                val selectedPlayer = mediaPlayersMap[selectedItem] ?: MediaPlayer().apply {
                    mediaPlayersMap[selectedItem] = this
                }
                previousPlayer = selectedPlayer
                selectedLink?.let {
                    selectedPlayer.reset()
                    selectedPlayer.setDataSource(it)
                    selectedPlayer.setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
                        mp.start()
                    }
                    selectedPlayer.prepareAsync()
                }
                previousPlayer = selectedPlayer
                mediaPlayersMap[selectedItem]= selectedPlayer
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // Doing nothing
            }
        }




    }
}
```

This error is showing up in logcat

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 21690
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:2148)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:518)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:957)
at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:946)
at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:910)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7666)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Could you please help me to fix this? I'm new to Coding.

Comment: When "the app crashes" you should post a stacktrace. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces